# How to unlock all tracks and cars?

Tags: colin-mcrae-rally-2005

The majority of cars (practically only 4WD vehicles are available) and more than half of the tracks are locked when starting a new game. Sadly unlocking content (campaign modes  are "championship" and "career") seems to be a very time-consuming process—my first cup victory, which took approximately half an hour, was awarded with one new car (tracks may have been unlocked, but it wasn't explicitly stated). I estimate the entire process to take dozens of hours.

[image: car selection]
[image: stage selection]

The game has a cheat menu in options > cheats, but I can't find a complete set of cheat codes online.

[image: cheat menu, phone numbers are censored]

Codemasters seems to charge for cheat codes even on the web ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/*/codemasters.com/bonuscodes/)):

[image: codemasters.com/bonuscodes]

I've even tried hex editing my save file following the instructions in [this guide](http://www.cheatbook.de/files/cmacr25.htm), but the given locations don't exist:

```
08 00 00 00 00 64 64 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 22 22 22 22 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 50 6C 61 79 65 72 20 30 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 6C 61 79 65 72 20 30 32 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 6C 61 79 65 72 20 30 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 6C 61 79 65 72 20 30 34 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 03 00 00 C8 00 00 00 D0 00 00 00 CB 00 00 00 CD 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 CB 00 00 00 CD 00 00 00 C8 00 00 00 D0 00 00 00 C8 00 00 00 D0 00 00 00 39 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 30 00 00 00 2F 00 00 00 31 00 00 00 CF 00 00 00 C9 00 00 00 D1 00 00 00 9D 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 1A 00 00 00 1B 00 00 00 1F 00 00 00 7D 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00
```

---

You can give both official (includes cheat codes) and unofficial methods in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to review the guide you have linked:

> To enable cheats without entering them, open your "options" file located in your 
>   savegame folder (c:\Colin2005\SG) with a hexeditor. Go to location "Ch" - this 
>   is the 13th position from the beginnig of the file and overwrite with "FF FF". 
>   Go to location "10h", this is the 16th position from the beginning of the file 
>   and overwrite with "FF FF".
>
> Now you have all cars, tracks and even the secret "mirror mode" activated! 
>   Overwrite both hex positions with "FF" only if you do not want the mirror mode.
>   Overwrite with "FF FF FF" to get small RC Cars!

I have highlighted the hex addresses that you need to amend to unlock cars, tracks, mirror mode and the small RC cars:

[image]

As in the original guide, just fill these values with FF.

**UPDATE**
Following the original guide works with the exception of unlocking group B vehicles.

[image: group B]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with hex editing. I struggle with understanding the coordinates. I only fully understand "`x`th" position and can only guess how to  find `Ch` and `10h` otherwise.

Comment: All tracks are now unlocked. All cars are unlocked, **with the exception of "[group B](https://i.imgur.com/re6BGNM.png)"**.

Comment: @user598527 - The h is telling you that this is expressed in the hex format.  Far right character for any hex code corresponds with looking down a column, whilst the other numbers are which line.  Example, "29h" would be looking down the 09 column, and across the ...00020 row.

Comment: @user598527 - unsure on group b.  Could be a case of trying to amend another batch of addresses.

Comment: Can you add the image and information about the group to your answer?

Comment: I don't actually know which hex addresses would work, and cannot test as I no longer have a copy of the game.  You can try changing the hex on 14h to FF, then try each subsequent address (to FF values).  That is what I would do in your situation.  Maybe try 0Fh and some of the earlier addresses too.

Comment: I understand, I mean adding "this unlocks all tracks and cars with the exception of group B".

Comment: Done, let me know if you find another address that unlocks group b.  Or post it as your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In these areas enter ff and 79 in the first two spaces and then ff and 79 in the second to unlock all cars and tracks without mirror screen mode. Good fun!!!

Comment: I'll test this as soon as I can!

Answer (score -1):

After trying different combinations of `FF` in those areas, I have found a way to get all cars, tracks AND Group B cars without mirrored tracks. In the first highlighted bit seen above, type in `FF 00 FF` and `FF FF FF` in the second highlighted bit.

Comment: I followed your instructions, but the group B is still locked (GOG version). I'm sending you my save file if you can take a look: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtHfOb9ltjABgbQiewclDMikXAPs4A (OneDrive link)

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, someone else did. Arqade community generally doesn't like answers which could be edits to the existing answer(s).